# Memory Leak of TIdCriticalSection.Create in IdThreadSafe.pas

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, indy

Utilizing TIdHttpServer and [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) in a Delphi 11 64-bit app, every time I close the app, with MadExcept set to report "Resource Leaks", I get two leaks, both with TIdCriticalSection in IdThreadSafe.pas and TCriticalSection in SyncObjs.pas.

This has all of the hallmarks of a "false flag" leak - i.e. MadExcept is reporting a leak that in reality doesn't exist. But I have to be sure.

Utilizing the old "ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True" does *not* report these 2 leaks...

Does anyone else see this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are actual leaks, and yes, this is intentional behavior.  See the comments at the bottom of Indy's `IdThread.pas` and `IdStack.pas` units.

That being said, they are *registered* leaks, so they should not appear in leak reports.  In Delphi 2006+. `System.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` is used, so if MadExcept hooks into the RTL properly (ie, provides a `TMemoryManagerEx.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak` callback that omits reported leaks from reports), it should pick up the registrations automatically.

Otherwise, for earlier versions, you can recompile Indy with `USE_MADEXCEPT` (or `USE_FASTMM4`, or `USE_LEAKCHECK` for other memory managers) defined in `IdCompilerDefines.inc` to enable leak registrations.

Otherwise, you can recompile Indy with `FREE_ON_FINAL` defined in `IdCompilerDefines.inc` to plug the leaks.

Comment: Thanks! Will try the conditional defines and see if one of them solves the issue.